# How to make a 3D surface of human body in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, 3d, cloud, point, geometry-surface

I searched through this site very much and studied the alike questions and used the answer codes given, but none worked. So I have to ask this question :

I have a Point Cloud ( Set of XYZs for a 3D surface ).
They actually belong to a 3D human body surface ( chest & back ).
I want to make a 3D surface using these points in MATLAB.
I've tried many ways but none worked unfortunately.

I'de be thankful if anybody could provide me some help on this matter.
Thank You

---

Actually I got an answer to this problem myself !! But I'm not totally sure on it.

I have to define how these points are connected via a face matrix. Like this :

```
Faces = [ 1 2 6 ; 1 2 4 ; 1 3 9 ; 2 6 8 ; ... ] ;
```

This means that points 1,2,6 for example are connected to each other as a face.
After defining the Face matrix, I have to use patch function to make a 3D surface based on the points (vertices) matrix and the faces matrix given.

An example code for such a thing could be like this :

```
patch('Vertices', P, 'Faces', t);
```

or

```
patch('Faces', t, 'Vertices', P, 'FaceColor', [1 0.75 0.65], 'EdgeColor', 'k', 'FaceAlpha', 1.0);
```

However, I face a new problem now, generating the face matrix!

Does anybody have any idea on it?

Thanks

Comment: How about showing at least some of the many ways you have tried?

Comment: These are some : meshgrid , scatter interpolation , conv hull , delaunay , . . . !!

Comment: yea tell us what you tried.  this is actually a well studied problem.  many papers have been published and patents have been filed on this topic.  one way is to convert your point cloud into a volume and use isosurface extraction (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isosurface.html).  there are many other ways.

Comment: I'de be grateful if you either answer me here or direct me to some links else than mathworks.com ; unfortunately I don't have access to mathworks.com right now. Thank You

Comment: "none worked"...well that really depends on what you count as "working"; I can't imagine that something as [TriScatterInterp](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/triscatteredinterpclass.html) would count as "not working", so please describe what you think counts as "working" :)

Comment: They work but not properly !! I want to plot the surface of a human body in chest & back ; But these functions give me something like a rounded cubic human-like box (!!) rather than the real 3d surface.

Comment: Please be more clear, otherwise we can't give you a good answer. What do you think is the "real" 3D surface?

Answer (score 0):

One method I can think of is using [Delaunay triangulation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delaunay.html) and [free boundary](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trirep.freeboundary.html).

```
% convert your X, Y, Z point cloud into a triangulated mesh
TRI = delaunay(X,Y,Z);
% get the outer boundary
[tri xf] = freeBoundary( TRI );
% plot
trisurf(tri, xf(:,1),xf(:,2),xf(:,3) );
```

Comment: Thanks for the help; but the code didn't work. The following error was given :  Undefined function or method 'freeBoundary' for input arguments of type 'double'.  I changed the delaunay to delaunaytri  and got sth but again it's more like a box rather than a human body !! If you want I can upload the result here.

Comment: unfortunately I couldn't upload the image result because I'm a new user !!

Comment: what matlab version are you using? please read the matlab doc for free boundary (link in answer).

Comment: I'm using MATLAB 2011 (7.1). Unfortunatelly I don't have access to mathworks.com right now.

Answer (score 0):

In place of delaunay just use DelaunayTri

```
TRI = DelaunayTri(X,Y,Z);[tri xf] = freeBoundary( TRI );trisurf(tri, xf(:,1),xf(:,2),xf(:,3) );
```